# Using numpy.nanargmin() in 2 dimensional matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to obtain the argmin of a numpy 2 dimensional array `A` which has `nan` values. Now the problem is:

1. `numpy.nanargmin(A)` returns only one index.
2. `numpy.unravel_index(A.argmin(), A.shape)` returns `[0,0]` because it has `nan` values.

   And...
3. `numpy.unravel_index(A.nanargmin(), A.shape)` throws the error:

   > AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
   >   last)  in ()
   >   ----> 1 np.unravel_index(dist.nanargmin(), dist.shape)  AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'nanargmin'

Comment: `np.unravel_index(np.nanargmin(A), A.shape)`  (In 1 you used `numpy.nanargmin(A)`; why did you switch to `A.nanargmin()` in 3?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NumPy arrays only have the `argmin()` attribute, but no `nanargmin()` attribute. So `A.nanargmin()` does not exist.

You can use `numpy.argmin(A)` and `numpy.nanargmin(A)` instead.